# Law of Iterated Expectations in Card Draw

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability, expectation

Here is a question which has boggled me in the understanding of the Law of Iterated Expectations(LIE). Consider a deck of $13$ cards numbered $\left\{1, 2, \cdots, 13\right\}$ being randomly drawn.

Let $X$ denote the value of the first card and $Y$ denote the value of the second card drawn. This is a case of drawing with no replacement so the card drawn at $X$ is not placed back and then the draw at $Y$ occurs. Find $\mathbb E (Y)$.

By LIE I know that $\mathbb E(Y) = \mathbb E[\mathbb E(Y|X)]$ so the working follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(Y) &= \mathbb E[\mathbb E(Y|X)]\\
&=\>?
\end{align}
$$

My attempted working
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(Y) &= \mathbb E[\mathbb E(Y|X)]\\
&= \mathbb E_X [\mathbb E(Y|X)]\\
&=\sum_{x=1}^{13}\frac{1}{13}\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{y=1 \cap y\neq x}^{13} \frac 1 {12}(Y=y|X=x)\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\frac{1}{13} \begin{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{90}{12}\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}\frac{89}{12}\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}\frac{88}{12}\end{pmatrix}+\cdots + \begin{pmatrix}\frac{78}{12}\end{pmatrix}\end{bmatrix} \\&=\frac{1092}{13\times 12}
\\&= 7
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb E (Y) = \mathbb E (X) = \displaystyle  \frac{1}{13} \sum_1^{13} x = 7$ so you seem to have the correct answer.

Comment: Hello Henry, $Y$ is drawn without replacement. Hence, I do not think I can simplistically use this method to solve for $\mathbb E (Y)$...I would love to but this is not the model.

Comment: @bryansis2010: Each of the $13$ cards is equally likely to drawn as the second card.  In calculating $\mathbb E (Y)$ directly, you do not know what $X$ is.

Comment: how do you prove that each of the 13 cards is equally likely to be drawn? I do know that each of the 12 cards remaining are equally likely to be drawn but what happens after that?

Comment: @bryansis2010:  a multitude of reasons, of which symmetry is the best. Here is another: the probability a particular card *is not* drawn first is $\frac{12}{13}$; if it is not drawn first, the probability it *is* drawn second is $\frac{1}{12}$, so the overall probability it is drawn second is $\frac{12}{13} \times \frac{1}{12} = \frac{1}{13}$